# What is the best way to create a menu bar that follows the MVVM paradigm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menu

This is my first question on SO, so *Hello*.

I'm pretty new to WPF and so I decided to try and create a GUI for a library I created in the past. I wanted to create a menu strip/line/bar for the application and this is pretty simple to do with the Menu control. However, I saw mentions of MVVM and looked it up, and decided I wanted to create the menu dynamically from a collection.

This is all well and good, I found a lot of material regarding the subject and ended up with the following ViewModel for my MenuItems:

```
class MenuItemViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>(children);
        }
    }

    private List<MenuItemViewModel> children;

    public MenuItemViewModel()
    {
        children = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();
    }
}
```

And the View (with extras):

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns=""
    "
    "
    Title="HTX-Formler" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
    </Style>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    DataType="{x:Type vm:MenuItemViewModel}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None">
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" />
</DockPanel>
```

As far as I can tell, the binding is fine, but whatever I do, I cannot get the menu to display anything what so ever.
I have a feeling it is because I am using the wrong ItemsSource, so I tried doing the following:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    #region Fields

    ReadOnlyCollection<MenuItemViewModel> _menuItems;

    #endregion

    #region Menu

    public ReadOnlyCollection<MenuItemViewModel> Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (_menuItems == null)
            {
                List<MenuItemViewModel> menuItems = this.PopulateMenu();
                _menuItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<MenuItemViewModel>(menuItems);
            }
            return _menuItems;
        }
    }

    List<MenuItemViewModel> PopulateMenu()
    {
        return new List<MenuItemViewModel>
        {
            new MenuItemViewModel()
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

But to no avail. I realise that the collection has the same name as the Children property, but changing the name of the col. has no effect.

**Summary**

What is the best way to create the menu bar in this way?
What is the best way to populate the menu collection?

A great deal of inspiration were taking from the following sources:

Yes, some of the links are to SO.
No, I do not think this is a duplicate question, as I think that the aforementioned sources are missing critical parts which are inherent to my understanding. If this is somehow a duplicate, I would appreciate it if someone would point out the information i missed.

I apologize for the triviality of this and knowing my brain, the answer is probably really simple, but I am literally at my wit's end here, so any and all answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you setting the menu's DataContext?

Comment: @Whyaduck Nowhere I guess and I guess part of what I do not understand, is where to put the collection that is bound to.
I understand that the DataContext can be specified in the code-behind (bad?) or in the parent element in the view, but I wouldn not know what to specify.

Comment: Your items datatemplate doesn't have any elements in it such as a TextBlock for display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution: set the `DataContext` in the window's constructor:

```
public class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I said, it was probably something really simple, like this. This is what happens when there isn't one definitive source on a subject.  
If you were to set the datacontext in the xaml, how would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `DataContext` of the entire Window in XAML by putting this in your Window definiton, e.g. below your `</Window.Resources>`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MenuItemViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```